# org.infinispan.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: ISPN000299: Unable to acquire lock after 15 seconds for key

Tags: hibernate, wildfly, infinispan

I have the following issue with Hibernate L2 cache :

- Thread 1

  - Execute native query : DELETE ... FROM  WHERE ... => whole L2 cache gets invalidated
  - Long process running
- Thread 2

  - Execute native query : UPDATE  SET ... WHERE ... => whole L2 cache gets invalidated
  - Thread is blocked by thread 1
  - After 15s, ISPN000299 is raised.

Here is the full stacktrace :

```
2020-03-11 15:06:01,384 ERROR [InvocationContextInterceptor] ISPN000136: Error executing command RemoveCommand, writing keys [com.sylob.cochise.dm1.ejb.entite.plageHoraire.PlageHoraireCoreEntite#4028ae256b033913016b0342b7ed6229]: org.infinispan.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: ISPN000299: Unable to acquire lock after 15 seconds for key com.sylob.cochise.dm1.ejb.entite.plageHoraire.PlageHoraireCoreEntite#4028ae256b033913016b0342b7ed6229 and requestor GlobalTransaction:<null>:1485:local. Lock is held by GlobalTransaction:<null>:1402:local
    at org.infinispan.util.concurrent.locks.impl.DefaultLockManager$KeyAwareExtendedLockPromise.lock(DefaultLockManager.java:238)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.AbstractLockingInterceptor.lockAndRecord(AbstractLockingInterceptor.java:193)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.AbstractTxLockingInterceptor.checkPendingAndLockKey(AbstractTxLockingInterceptor.java:193)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.AbstractTxLockingInterceptor.lockOrRegisterBackupLock(AbstractTxLockingInterceptor.java:116)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.PessimisticLockingInterceptor.visitDataWriteCommand(PessimisticLockingInterceptor.java:134)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.AbstractLockingInterceptor.visitRemoveCommand(AbstractLockingInterceptor.java:75)
    at org.infinispan.commands.write.RemoveCommand.acceptVisitor(RemoveCommand.java:67)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.TxInterceptor.enlistWriteAndInvokeNext(TxInterceptor.java:367)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.TxInterceptor.visitRemoveCommand(TxInterceptor.java:231)
    at org.infinispan.commands.write.RemoveCommand.acceptVisitor(RemoveCommand.java:67)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.InvocationContextInterceptor.handleAll(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:114)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.InvocationContextInterceptor.handleDefault(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.infinispan.commands.AbstractVisitor.visitRemoveCommand(AbstractVisitor.java:48)
    at org.infinispan.commands.write.RemoveCommand.acceptVisitor(RemoveCommand.java:67)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.InterceptorChain.invoke(InterceptorChain.java:335)
    at org.infinispan.cache.impl.CacheImpl.executeCommandAndCommitIfNeeded(CacheImpl.java:1672)
    at org.infinispan.cache.impl.CacheImpl.removeInternal(CacheImpl.java:557)
    at org.infinispan.cache.impl.CacheImpl.remove(CacheImpl.java:549)
    at org.infinispan.cache.impl.CacheImpl.remove(CacheImpl.java:543)
    at org.infinispan.cache.impl.AbstractDelegatingCache.remove(AbstractDelegatingCache.java:296)
    at org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.util.Caches.removeAll(Caches.java:285)
    at org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.access.InvalidationCacheAccessDelegate.removeAll(InvalidationCacheAccessDelegate.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.entity.ReadOnlyAccess.removeAll(ReadOnlyAccess.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.BulkOperationCleanupAction$EntityCleanup.<init>(BulkOperationCleanupAction.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.BulkOperationCleanupAction$EntityCleanup.<init>(BulkOperationCleanupAction.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.BulkOperationCleanupAction.<init>(BulkOperationCleanupAction.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.NativeSQLQueryPlan.coordinateSharedCacheCleanup(NativeSQLQueryPlan.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.NativeSQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(NativeSQLQueryPlan.java:176)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.executeNativeUpdate(SessionImpl.java:1373)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl.executeUpdate(SQLQueryImpl.java:373)
```

I'm running Wildfly 10.1.0.Final (standalone full profile) with Hibernate 5.0.10.Final / Infinispan 8.2.4.Final.
Environment is NOT clustered and sessions are NOT replicated.

I'm using the default config provided by Wildfly for Infinispan L2 cache :

```
<cache-container name="hibernate" default-cache="local-query" module="org.hibernate.infinispan">
    <local-cache name="entity">
        <transaction mode="NON_XA"/>
        <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
        <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
    </local-cache>
    <local-cache name="local-query">
        <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
        <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
    </local-cache>
    <local-cache name="timestamps"/>
</cache-container>
```

With Hibernate 3.x / EhCache, this used to work.

What's wrong here ?

Any support appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

Native SQL batch update invalidates the whole L2 cache. This isn't what you want. So you must tell hibernate otherwise by using, for example:

```
query.unwrap(SQLQuery.class).addSynchronizedEntityClass(YourEntity.class).executeUpdate();
```

This should avoid invalidating the whole cache.

Also, take look at the class org.hibernate.action.internal.BulkOperationCleanupAction

reference: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-second-level-cache
see item 10.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, nothing is wrong. However due to some constraints (trying to be correct') both of these try to remove entries one-by-one in single transaction, and that can really take a long time.

WildFly 10 is more than 4 years old and so is Hibernate 5.0.10. I don't recall in which minor/micro version what got fixed but with a recent-enough release of Hibernate you should go with `<transaction mode="NONE"/>` and while the DB transactional semantics will be upheld this problem should go away.